# How can i update treeview node?

Tags: c#, treeview

I'm using v.s 2008 with c#.

I have a treeview on a master page. And i want to change a node's text. if current user's id isn't equels 222.

```
if (kul.M_Kullanici_id != 222)
   {
       tvMaind.Nodes[0].ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[0].Text = "çağın";
   }
```

My treeview is a sitemap. And t.v has xmldatasource. 
i wanna rename a node's text when user which has 222 id. I m looking current user in masterpage onunload event. and i m changing text. i can see that change on watch. but in cant see change on the page. I thing xmlsource reload after i change node's text.

thanks for your helps.

Comment: Could you be more descriptive? What is the structure of the tree and what identifies the node you want to update. Last but not least: what have you tried and what errors do you get?

Comment: Are you testing this using id 222?

Comment: yes sure compiler is entering that block.

Answer (score 1):

You just retrieve required TreeNode and set its Text property.

```
> tvMenu.Nodes[I].Text = ""; // I: index of node to be retrieved.
```

Comment: @cagin: do you have any error? shall you tell me the node you need to identify?

Comment: No i havent any error. but any changes on the treeview. I thinnk that treeview reload from xml when i changed node's text. I change that on unload event of masterpage.

Comment: I afraid I cannot understand you, what do you mean by "I think that treeview reload from xml when i changed node's text"?

Comment: Okay. My treeview is a sitemap. And t.v has xmldatasource. 
i wanna rename a node's text when user which has 222 id. I m looking current user in masterpage onunload event. and i m changing text. i can see that change on watch. but in cant see change on the page. I thing xmlsource reload after i change node's text.

Comment: @cagin: try to update node text after binding treeview to xmldatasource, this will solve your issue.